# Why "расчёт" but "рассчитывать"

Tags: орфография

Why "расчёт" with one "с" and "рассчитывать" with two "с"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two almost synonymous¹ verbs: *расче́сть* and *рассчита́ть*. The former decomposes into morphemes *рас-чес-ть*, the latter – *рас-с-чит-а-ть*. The former produces a noun *расчёт* in an obvious way, the latter – *рассчёт*. Both were equally widely used until the early XX century: [*расчетъ*](https://www.google.ru/search?num=100&hl=ru&tbm=bks&q=%22%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8A%22) and [*разсчетъ*](https://www.google.ru/search?num=100&hl=ru&tbm=bks&q=%22%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8A%22) as they were spelled at that time.

So the absence of word *рассчёт* in modern language is nothing but one of arbitrary decisions of ‘fathers’ of Russian orthography. I can’t say right now whose exactly.

<sup>1) *расче́сть* is quite rare nowadays</sup>

---

---

Есть два практически полностью синонимичных¹ глагола: *расче́сть* и *рассчита́ть*. Первый раскладывается на морфемы *рас-чес-ть*, второй — *рас-с-чит-а-ть*. От первого очевидным образом образуется существительное *расчёт*, от второго — *рассчёт*. Оба они одинаково широко употреблялись до начала XX века, в тогдашей орфографии: [*расчетъ*](https://www.google.ru/search?num=100&hl=ru&tbm=bks&q=%22%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8A%22) и [*разсчетъ*](https://www.google.ru/search?num=100&hl=ru&tbm=bks&q=%22%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8A%22).

Так что отсутствие слова *рассчёт* в современном языке — это не более чем одно из волюнтаристских решений «отцов» русской орфографии. Чье именно, сходу не скажу.

<sup>1) *расче́сть* — слово ныне редкое</sup>